# Running time for matrix multiplication in R (operator %*%)

Tags: matrix-multiplication

Is there any way to estimate how long (roughly) take a matrix multiplication in R according the dimension of the matrices?

I have a  multiplication of a matrix of dimensions 14500 rows by 130000 columns for its transpose (130000 x 14500).

Comment: I don't know of any methods to estimate runtime. Have you tried a smaller size matrix, and investigating the time it takes for increasingly large matrices? The time will also heavily depend on the system. What keeps you from just performing the operation and measure the time?

Comment: The time complexity for `AA^T` where `A` is `m x n` is `O(m * n * m)`. Try timing a `1450 x 13000` matrix and then multiply the time by 1000, that should get you pretty close.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I just wanna know if it is something doable in a reasonable time or it would be too much. @CJR I am not sure if I follow in your calculation, do you mean 1450*13000*1000??

Comment: If it takes 1 second to calculate `AA^T` for a matrix A that is `1450 x 13000` it will take ~1000 seconds for a matrix A that is `14500 x 130000`. If it takes 1 second to calculate `AA^T` for a matrix A that is `145 x 1300` it will take ~1 million seconds for a matrix A that is `14500 x 130000`. So time one of those smaller matrix products and use that measurement to figure out what you'd expect for your full-size matrices.